# Statistics and R: Determine if N-dimensional vectors are all similar

Tags: r

I need to see if all 35 vectors of 120 dimensions are similar, to prove the hypothesis that they are not. I used euclidean distance and cosine similarity and by learning through this forum I got a similarity matrix.

(its a lot of data so I will summarize this point in R code)

```
matrix<-cbind( 35 vectors) #matrix is then 120x35
sim1<-cosine(matrix)
dist1<-as.matrix(dist(t(matrix), diag= TRUE, method="euclidean"))
```

But, the thing is that cosine compares vector_i with vector_j, and I would prefer to see vector_i with the rest of the vectors and evaluate a p-value of some sort. For me, it would be like:

```
similarity(vector_i, other vectors)>0.90 --> vector_i is similar to the other vectors
```

With similarity hopefully being like cosine similarity, as it is more about direction than magnitude.

Does anyone have a recommendation or know a similarity criteria for these problems?

I am starting to use R, so if you know a test that is implemented there, i would be very grateful.

PD1>Statistics was a class I took a loong time ago, sorry if there are misunderstandings)
PD2>the value of each dimension can go between 0 and 1, and many times it is 0, so I think that chi squared might not be ok for this...

Comment: Tip: To get the most out of SO, you should always include a reproducible example (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html) and show, what you did (, and why it's not sufficient).

Comment: You will need to be a bit more precise in what exactly you mean by "similar". What level of dissimilarity should be detected as abnormal? Or is the null hypothesis that the 35 vectors are all identical, in which case you could look at `all.equal()`.

Comment: Thanks @lukeA. I have the following at the moment (its a lot of data so I will summarize in R code)
matrix<-cbind( **35 vectors**) #matrix is then 120x35
sim1<-cosine(matrix)
dist1<-as.matrix(dist(t(matrix), diag= TRUE, method="euclidean"))

StephanKolassa Included now.

Comment: In addition, since you will probably first need to address the statistical issues involved (operationalizing "similarity") before you can try solving the problem in R, I flagged this question for migration to CrossValidated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a similarity measure like cosine or euclidean distance you should know that your are building a matrix of size m x m where m is the number of records (In this case, 35). So you can compare vector_i with the rest vectors. Supose you want to compare vector 7 with vector 17 and vector 34.... Just check the matrix in positions (7,17) and (7,34): that gives you the similarity you are looking for.

Of course, you can use different similarity functions, just take a look to Kernel Methods. Something like http://www.kernel-methods.net/tutorials/KMtalk.pdf is very useful. A Kernel, in few words, uses similarity functions to determine if a record is close or far from another record. Maybe in a low dimensional space, vector_i and vector_j seem to be close, but with a Kernel (in a high dimensional space: feature space), you realize that both vector can be far away. Examples of kernel are dot product, polynomial, RBF, etc.

In R, you can use the e1071 package.

I hope this help you!